# Exception when parsing structure.rdf.u8, using Jena

Tags: java, exception, jena, dmoz

```
 Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
 InputStream in = FileManager.get().open( "W:\\structure.rdf.u8" );
 model.read(in, null);
 model.write(System.out);
```

I use the above code, which is provided in the [Jena](https://jena.apache.org/tutorials/rdf_api.html) documentation, to parse the [ODP](http://rdf.dmoz.org/rdf/structure.rdf.u8.gz). First it gave some exception, so I added all the **jar** files in the Jena package and got the following long exception:

```
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.jena.riot.system.stream.JenaIOEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.jena.riot.RiotException: [line: 5, col: 5 ] {E201} The attributes on this property element, are not permitted with any content; expecting end element tag.
    at org.apache.jena.riot.system.ErrorHandlerFactory$ErrorHandlerStd.error(ErrorHandlerFactory.java:128)
    at org.apache.jena.riot.lang.LangRDFXML$ErrorHandlerBridge.error(LangRDFXML.java:246)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.impl.ARPSaxErrorHandler.error(ARPSaxErrorHandler.java:37)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.impl.XMLHandler.warning(XMLHandler.java:196)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.impl.XMLHandler.warning(XMLHandler.java:173)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.impl.XMLHandler.warning(XMLHandler.java:168)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.impl.ParserSupport.warning(ParserSupport.java:194)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.states.Frame.warning(Frame.java:55)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.states.WantEmpty.characters(WantEmpty.java:33)
    at org.apache.jena.rdfxml.xmlinput.impl.XMLHandler.characters(XMLHandler.java:137)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.characters(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNamespaceBinder.characters(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanContent(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
```

`

I don't know if I need to remove some of the **jar** files to fix this or the code provided in the Apache site is wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, but could there be a syntax error in your RDF/XML file?

Comment: @marstran that is very unlikely. ODP is widely used by search engines for SERP representation.

Comment: We need to see the file here, it sounds like there is something broken there.

Comment: The 'ODP' link is to the Jena documentation as well.  Did you mean http://rdf.dmoz.org/rdf/structure.rdf.u8.gz?

Comment: @AndyS oh, my bad. yes, that is right

Comment: @user205512 the wrong link has been fixed

Answer (score 0):

It's not legal RDF/XML; close but has errors.
(at least the one `http://rdf.dmoz.org/rdf/structure.rdf.u8.gz` isn't)

1. Top level 'RDF' is not the RDF marker RDF, it's http://dmoz.org/rdf/RDF It should be r:RDF but then ...
2. The `r` namespace is wrong (should be `http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#`, not `http://www.w3.org/TR/RDF/`).

Comment: so, how come all search engines are using this ODP with no problem?

Comment: to be honest, did not get your answer.

Comment: do you mean that Jena is not following standard RDF?

Comment: Maybe search engines use the file as XML, not RDF.

Comment: I described the problems relative to the specification.

Comment: If so, then how can I use same file as XML?

Comment: About the answer, you mentioned things that are blur to me. For example, you are talking `r` name space which i can not find it.

Comment: The file structure.rdf.u8.gz has xmlns:r= defined at the top.

Comment: How could you even open such heavy file in notepad? every time i tried to open it, it hanged. (used more than 1.7Gb system's memory) but for my own information, I want to know whether or not if I replace your correction with the faulty ones in the file would fix the problem?

Comment: I opened a lighter version of similar file, replaced `http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#` with `http://www.w3.org/TR/RDF/`. but about #1, I cannot get it. the `xmlns="http://dmoz.org/rdf/"` should be changed to what?

Comment: I still did not get an answer for `How to use the XML version and not the RDF` if it is the case for search engines to use same RDF with no problem.

Comment: I looked in the file with "gzip -d < structure.rdf.u8.gz | head -100".

Comment: See above: It should be r:RDF (and the same change at the end of the file.

Comment: You have to use the RDF namespace `xmlns:r="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"` then `r:RDF`.